# Dynamic Radiobutton in Flash Builder 4.6 - How to make it multiline?

Tags: flash, apache-flex, radio-button

I am making a quiz application for mobile.The questions are comming from  xml.
How can i make multiline Radiobuttons? I tried to do a skinclass but it didn't worked.
In this code i make the RadioButtons.

```
enterfor (j=0; j<arrAnswers[index].length; j++) {
            arrChoices[j] = new RadioButton()

            arrChoices[j].label = arrAnswers[index][j];
            arrChoices[j].value = j;
            arrChoices[j].width = qField.width;
            arrChoices[j].x = qField.x + 10;
            arrChoices[j].y = qField.y + qHeight + (aHeight+5)*j;
            arrChoices[j].group = rbg

            container.addElement(arrChoices[j]);

        } code here
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer following links:
http://blog.flexexamples.com/2010/04/10/creating-a-multiline-spark-radiobutton-control-in-flex-4/

http://blogs.adobe.com/aharui/2007/04/multiline_buttons.html

Download the code from `blogs.adobe.com` and use your custom radiobutton

```
var radiobtn:MultilineRadioButton=new MultilineRadioButton();
```

Comment: Thank you M.SNayak! I found that too, but with 4.6 i count get it to work. Maybe i did something wrong. At the first example it makes Radiobutton from mxml. How can i refer to a style in actionscript?

Comment: In other case i used `mycomponent.setStyle` property but in this case I don't have much idea about that :( .

Comment: Ye i tried the Flex 4 tutorial and i get a warning at the begining -

Description Resource Path Location Type
CSS type selectors are not supported in components: 'spark.components.RadioButton' RadioparaHomeView.mxml /Radiopara/src/views line 12 Flex Problem

Comment: see [http://stackoverflow.com/a/1729097/842112] and http://parallaxed.net/article/css-type-selectors-are-not-supported-in-components